# Data design & efficiency: get members from all child groups (nested)

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, performance

I have 2 tables which defined members and their groups like so:

```
[Table member]
memberID | groupID
1        | 101
2        | 104
...      | ...

[Table group]
groupID | parentID
1       | NULL
101     | 1
102     | 1
103     | 101
104     | 103
...     | ...
```

And in my page, if I want to get all members from a particular group (including their child groups), e.g. get all members from group 1, I have to:

> step 1: get groupIDs for group 1 and its children and its children's children and ...
>
> step 2: SELECT * FROM member WHERE groupID in (....."groupIDs grabbed in step 1"....)

**In my database, there're about 3M members and 50K groups contained in each table, if a requested group is a top level node, it has thousands of child groups, and query may become very slow.**

Is there a better way to re-design these table structures for member-group relation  and make my query run faster ?

any alternative solutions like caching are also welcomed.

Comment: If perfomance of getting the subgroups' tree is a primary concern look at nested set model for trees. It requires a good deal more efforts to modify a tree but just that query is ligthing fast.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you can store hierarchical data in sql server

1. The way you have done.
2. or by using sql server advance data type [`hierarchyid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173(v=sql.105).aspx).

But SQL server isn't really a tool to handle the hierarchical data and it becomes really difficult to do the simplest task.

In your case the best option would be to have Two separate tables for Users and Groups e.g.

**Users**

```
UserID   UserName 
  1      User1
  2      User2
  3      User3
```

**Groups**

```
GroupID   GroupName 
  1        Group1
  2        Group2
  3        Group3
```

And then finally a Third table to store data For `Users` and Their `Group` Memberships. Where `UserID` column referrences back to `User` table and `GroupID` column referrences back to `Group` table.

**UserGroup**

```
UserID    GroupID
  1          1
  1          2
  2          1
  2          2
  2          3
  3          3
```

So your tables would end up having the following relations

```
User    -->   One to Many   --> UserGroup 

Groups  -->   One to Many   --> UserGroup

                               /------->  User    
UserGroup --> Many to Many  --/
                              \
                               \-------> Groups
```